# Telnet from command line doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, telnet

I want to open `Telnet` session from command line via .NET.
This command works fine manually:

```
telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

So i try to open it via .NET

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I am using `Wireshark` to check if this start the traffic and here it seems that nothing happen and i cannot see any `Telnet` traffic.

Comment: Your snippet surely isn't what you are really using.  Telnet needs to emulate a terminal, that prevents I/O redirection from working.  Just don't use another program to do this, telnet is a *very* simple protocol when terminal emulation is not required.  Use the TcpClient class, port 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ProcessWindowStyle.Normal` instead you would see you are not actually executing telnet. You must add the "/C" parameter if you want the CMD window to close after finishing or "/K" if you want it to remain open.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

After you get the behavior you want, then of course switch back to `Hidden`.